# Google maps V3 custom route via given lat/lng points

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hey there,
I have a GPS module in my car and it saves every 30 seconds my position and then it exports those points of the entire travel. So when I drive about 5 hours, it has about 600 waypoints stored. Now I want to show my trip in google map. One of the soulutions is to generate a .kml file and then draw a polyline inside the map. But because it stores position every 30 seconds, the line is often "off-road". Is there a way google will draw this way exactly on the road? the route() function is useless because of limit of waypoints (i think 8).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing the exact same thing today and have come to the conclusion that the frequency of acquiring the co-ordinates should be a function of distance covered rather than being dependent on time. I have kept the threshold distance as 10m and have been able to resolve most of the instances of the lines going off the road.

Answer (score 0):

Er just saw that this question was asked some time ago >_> maybe it will help someone anyway.

If you have enough time you could preprocess the data. Method won't work if you don't have your own server - really rough outline of my thoughts:

```
var path = [];
var index = 0;
function getRoute() {
    thisRoute = getRoute(yourPoints[index], yourPoints[index+=10]);
    index+=10;
    for(each step in thisRoute)
        path.append(step);
    if (index < yourPoints.length)
        setTimeout(getRoute(), 1000); // or however long it takes for you to be able to get directions again
    else 
        store path in local file which is used later on when you need the full path
}
```

So to do this you need some way to store the path - I would use my own server and PHP, or there may be other ways that I'm not aware of. When I want to show the path I would retrieve it again using PHP, then draw it with polylines. There are examples around the place for the `path.append(step)`. I'm sure there are better ways to do it (maybe python rather than JS) but this is the general approach I would take.